# Can you identify this LEGO plane set?

Tags: set-identification, vehicle

Sadly this LEGO plane crashed today. No one was injured, but I do not know where the instructions are, or the LEGO kit/product number. Can someone help me identify which kit it is so I can look up the instructions online?

[image: Plane - Top View]

[image: Plane - Bottom View]

Answer (score 12):

That's one of the alternate models for [Ocean Explorer (31045)](https://brickset.com/sets/31045-1/Ocean-Explorer):

[image: 31045 back of box]

The [instructions are available on LEGO.com](https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/6146024.pdf).